# How to handle mongoid custom type dirty tracking?

Tags: ruby, mongoid, geojson

I've got the following custom field type that allows me to save a GeoJSON LineString while treating the field like an array of points:

```
class GeoLineString

  attr_reader :coordinates

  def initialize(array)
    @coordinates = array
  end

  # Converts an object of this instance into a database friendly value.
  def mongoize
    {
        "type" => "LineString",
        "coordinates" => @coordinates
    }
  end

  def as_json(options={})
    mongoize
  end

  class << self

    # Get the object as it was stored in the database, and instantiate
    # this custom class from it.
    def demongoize(object)
      return self.new(object["coordinates"]) if object.is_a?(Hash)
    end

    # Takes any possible object and converts it to how it would be
    # stored in the database.
    def mongoize(object)
      case object
        when GeoLineString then object.mongoize
        when Array then GeoLineString.new(object).mongoize
        else object
      end
    end

    # Converts the object that was supplied to a criteria and converts it
    # into a database friendly form.
    def evolve(object)
      case object
        when GeoLineString then object.mongoize
        else object
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which i use as follows in my model:

```
class Track
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String
  field :coordinates, type: ::GeoLineString
  index({ coordinates: "2dsphere" }, { min: -200, max: 200 })
end
```

This works as expected but when i want to change the coordinates inside of the GeoLineString field mongoid does not recognize the field "coordinates" as dirty an thus does not update it in the database. Example:

```
t=Track.last
=> #<Track _id: 568a70e6859c862ee1000000, created_at: 2016-01-04 13:17:40 UTC, updated_at: 2016-01-04 13:17:40 UTC, name: nil, coordinates: {"type"=>"LineString", "coordinates"=>[[1, 2], [2, 2]]}>

t.coordinates.coordinates.push([3,3])

t
=> #<Track _id: 568a70e6859c862ee1000000, created_at: 2016-01-04 13:17:40 UTC, updated_at: 2016-01-04 13:17:40 UTC, name: nil, coordinates: {"type"=>"LineString", "coordinates"=>[[1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3]]}>

t.changed?
=> false
```

How can i get mongoid to recognize that the value has changed?

Comment: Couldn't you just go with `+=` instead of `push`? i.e. create new objects rather than modify them in-place. Usually its either that, manually dirtying things, or switching to embedding.

Comment: I think the problem ist that it is still the same instance of GeoLineString, its not connected to how i change the array content.

Comment: That sounds about right but by "go with `+=`" I'm trying to say "create a new `GeoLineString`". I'm not aware of any special per-type "has it changed?" logic, I think you're stuck with changing the object (not just its content) or manually marking things as dirty.

Comment: How do i manually mark it as dirty?

Comment: Start with https://www.google.ca/#q=mongoid+dirty